# Trying to tunnel through https via a proxy built from ground up browser never responds back?

Tags: java, browser

Due to a variety of reasons it became necessary to create our own proxy. Everything is working as it should through HTTP. As soon as we receive a CONNECT to tunnel through SSL is when everything goes wrong. What we do logically is take the CONNECT parse out the host and port so we know where we are sending future ssl requests and create a request to send back to the browser stating we have successfully made the ssl handshake like so:

HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\nProxy-agent: test\r\n\r\n

What we expect to happen is that the browser once receiving this successful message will send us the next https request. However, instead we get sent another CONNECT request over and over.It is clear that is does not like the response we send back. The problem is that i'm not exactly sure why? Does the response back need to be sent back via an https socket? I just don't understand this process enough to move forward.

Here is my server class:

```
public class HttpServer extends Observable implements IWebServer, Runnable
{
int Port = -1;
int State = HttpState.IDLE;
ArrayList<WebTransactionEvent> History = new ArrayList<WebTransactionEvent>();
ArrayList<HttpService> myServices = new ArrayList<HttpService>();

SocketChannel myChannel = null;
boolean needResponse = false;
boolean shouldStop;
Logger logger = OpsToolsLogger.getLogger(HttpServer.class.getName());
Selector selector ;
static Hashtable<String, HttpServer> myInstances = new Hashtable<String, HttpServer>(); 
Hashtable<HttpTransaction, HttpService> myTaskTable = new Hashtable<HttpTransaction, HttpService>(); 
Vector<HttpTransaction> transactionQueue = new Vector<HttpTransaction>(); 

private HttpServer(){}

private HttpServer(int Port) 
{
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "HttpServer: startup - listening to port: " + Port);
    this.Port = Port;
    shouldStop = false;

    // Create the selector
    try {
            selector = Selector.open();
            ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            serverChannel.configureBlocking(false);
            serverChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(Port));
            this.registerSocket(serverChannel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public static HttpServer getInstance(String port)
{
    if( !myInstances.containsKey( port ) )
    {   
        myInstances.put( port, new HttpServer(Integer.parseInt(port)));
    }

    return myInstances.get(port);
}

public int getState()
{
    return State;
}

public void stop()
{
    shouldStop = true;
}

public boolean needResponse()
{
    return needResponse;
}

public HttpTransaction getNextTransaction()
{
    if(transactionQueue.isEmpty())
    {
        return null;
    }
    //System.out.println("grabbing next trans");
    HttpTransaction temp = transactionQueue.firstElement();
    transactionQueue.remove(0);//pop trans from  queue
    return temp;
}

public void dropTransaction()
{
    myTaskTable.clear();
    needResponse = false;

}

public synchronized boolean respond(HttpTransaction transaction, IHttpResponse editedResponse, boolean closeConnection)
{
    logger.log(Level.FINE, "HttpServer: responding ");
    needResponse = false;
    if(myTaskTable.isEmpty())
    {
        return false;
    }

    //see if there isn't a service object registered with that transaction
    if(!myTaskTable.containsKey(transaction))
    {
        return false;
    }

    State = HttpState.SENDING_RESPONSE;
    ManipulatedHttpTransaction myTrans = (ManipulatedHttpTransaction) transaction;
    HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) editedResponse;
    myTrans.setManipulatedResponse( response );
    HttpService serv = myTaskTable.get(transaction);
    if(!serv.respond(myTrans.getManipulatedResponse(), closeConnection))
    {
        History.add( new WebTransactionEvent( myTrans, WebTransactionEvent.TRANSACTION_ERROR ) );
        return false;
    }

    myTaskTable.remove(transaction);

    History.add( new WebTransactionEvent( myTrans, WebTransactionEvent.TRANSACTION_COMPLETED ) );

    needResponse = !myTaskTable.isEmpty();

    return true;
}

public void registerSocket(ServerSocketChannel theSocket)
{
    try {
        theSocket.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
    } catch (ClosedChannelException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    try {

        while (!shouldStop ) {
            // Wait for an event
            selector.select();

            // Get list of selection keys with pending events
            Iterator it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();

            // Process each key
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                // Get the selection key
                SelectionKey selKey = (SelectionKey)it.next();

                // Remove it from the list to indicate that it is being processed
                it.remove();

                // Check if it's a connection request
                if (selKey.isAcceptable()) {
                    // Get channel with connection request
                   ServerSocketChannel ssChannel = (ServerSocketChannel)selKey.channel();
                   SocketChannel theChannel =  ssChannel.accept();
                   if(theChannel != null)
                    {

                        logger.log(Level.FINEST, "HttpServer: Connection established");

                        try
                        {
                            theChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "myChannel = null ( configureBlocking() )");
                            //bytesRead = -1;
                        }

                        myServices.add( new HttpService(this, theChannel ) );
                        needResponse = true;

                    }

                    //needResponse = !myTaskTable.isEmpty();                
                    //System.out.println("need response: "+ needResponse);

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    //shutdown
    logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Server stopping - " + Port);
}

public ArrayList<WebTransactionEvent> getHistory() 
{
    return new ArrayList<WebTransactionEvent>(History);
}

public boolean switchServerToSSL()
{
    //HttpService tempService = myTaskTable.get(PendingTransaction);
    //tempService.useSSL = true;
    return true;
}

/**
 * Adds the transaction from browser to the transaction queue and also ties it to a service by adding it to myTasks map
 * @param myTrans
 * @param httpService
 */
public void addTransaction(ManipulatedHttpTransaction myTrans,
        HttpService httpService) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //ensure vector has room to add another transaction
    if(transactionQueue.capacity() <= transactionQueue.size())
        transactionQueue.ensureCapacity(transactionQueue.size() * 2);

    transactionQueue.add(myTrans);//add transaction to queue
    myTaskTable.put(myTrans, httpService);//tie the transaction toits service
   // System.out.println("server notifying proxy: " + myTrans.getFullURL());
    this.setChanged();
    this.notifyObservers(myTrans);
}
```

}

Here is portion in proxy that handles a CONNECT:

```
if(tempTransaction.getOriginatingRequest().getMethod().contentEquals("CONNECT"))
            {
                /*tell the browser that the connection exists
                 * 
                 * Each time you connect to an SSL-protected website, Burp generates a server certificate for that host, signed by the CA certificate
                 * 
                 * The server certificates presented to the client (i.e. a web browser) are dynamically generated/signed by the proxy and contain most of the same fields as the original webserver certificate. The subject DN, serial number, validity dates, and extensions are preserved. However, the issuer DN is now set to the name of the proxy's self-signed 
                 * certificate and the public/private keys of the proxy are used in creating the forged certificate. These forged certificates are cached (in memory) by the proxy, for better performance
                 */
                HttpResponse tunnelResponse = new HttpResponse("HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\nProxy-agent: Ops Assistant\r\n\r\n");
                tempTransaction.setResponse(tunnelResponse);

                if(!finishResponse2(tempTransaction,tempTransaction.getResponse(), false));
                {
                    //close the connection
                }

                myServer.switchServerToSSL();
            }
```

Here is section sends request back to browser:

```
 public boolean respond(IHttpResponse response, boolean closeConnection)
{
    isCloseConnectionRequested = closeConnection;

    try 
    {
        if(useSSL)
        {
            ByteBuffer tmpBuffer = response.getData();
            tmpBuffer.position(0);
            myConnection.SecureWrite( tmpBuffer );
        }
        else
        {
            ByteBuffer tmpBuffer = response.getData();
            tmpBuffer.position(0);
            myConnection.Write(tmpBuffer);
        }
        if(closeConnection)
        {
            myChannel.close();
            myChannel = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        isResponded = true;
        return false;
    }

    isResponded = true;
    return true;

}
```

Probably most important the socket class:

```
 public class SocketConnection implements IConnection
   {

public SocketChannel theSocketChannel;
public InetSocketAddress theRemoteAddress;
public int TimeoutThreshold;

private int TimeOutThreshold = 30;
private SSLEngine theSSLEngine;
private SSLContext theSSLContext;
private ByteBuffer inNetworkDataBuffer;
private ByteBuffer inAppDataBuffer;
private ByteBuffer outNetworkDataBuffer;
private ByteBuffer outAppDataBuffer;

//create outbound connection to host/port
public SocketConnection(String Host, int Port ) throws IOException
{
    theRemoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress( Host, Port);
    theSocketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
    theSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    theSocketChannel.connect( theRemoteAddress );
    theSocketChannel.finishConnect();
}

//use existing socket connection
public SocketConnection(SocketChannel existingChannel) throws IOException
{
    theSocketChannel = existingChannel;
    theSocketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    theRemoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress( existingChannel.socket().getInetAddress(), existingChannel.socket().getPort() );
}

public boolean setTimeOut(int newTimeOutThreshold) 
{
    TimeOutThreshold = newTimeOutThreshold; 
    return true;
}

public void waitForSocketToConnect() throws Exception
{
    int i = 0;
    while( !this.isConnected() )
    {
        this.finishConnect();
        if(i>=3000)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        i++;

        try{Thread.sleep(10);}catch(Exception e){}
    }
}

public boolean Write( ByteBuffer DataToSend )
{
    try 
    {
        //DataToSend.flip();
        int numBytesWritten = theSocketChannel.write(DataToSend);
        try
        {
            DataToSend.compact();
        }
        catch (ReadOnlyBufferException e)
        {
            DataToSend.rewind();
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // Connection may have been closed
    }

    return true;
}

public ByteBuffer Read()
{   
    ByteBuffer ResponseBytes = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0);

    try 
    {
        ByteBuffer netBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[10000]);


        // Clear the buffer and read bytes from socket
        netBuffer.clear();

        int numBytesRead = theSocketChannel.read(netBuffer);
        if(numBytesRead == -1)
            return null; //-1 means we done return null as the flag
        netBuffer.flip();

        ByteBuffer tempBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[ ResponseBytes.limit() + netBuffer.limit() ]);
        ResponseBytes.position(0);
        netBuffer.position(0);
        tempBuffer.put(ResponseBytes);
        tempBuffer.put(netBuffer);
        netBuffer.flip();
        ResponseBytes = tempBuffer;

    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // Connection may have been closed
        e = e;
        return ByteBuffer.wrap( e.getMessage().getBytes() );
    }

    return (ByteBuffer) ResponseBytes.flip();

}

public boolean SecureWrite( ByteBuffer DataToSend )
{
    boolean writeSuccess = true;

    try
    {
        //if we don't have a SSLEngine make one
        if(theSSLEngine==null)
        {
            setupSSL();
        }

        //Convert Data 
        outAppDataBuffer.clear();
        outAppDataBuffer.put(DataToSend);
        outAppDataBuffer.flip();
        SSLEngineResult sslResult = theSSLEngine.wrap(outAppDataBuffer, outNetworkDataBuffer);
        outAppDataBuffer.compact();  
        //outNetworkDataBuffer.flip();
        //int numBytesWritten = theSocketChannel.write(outNetworkDataBuffer);
        if(sslResult.getStatus() == SSLEngineResult.Status.OK)
        {
            if(sslResult.getHandshakeStatus() != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NOT_HANDSHAKING)
            {   
                // Write bytes
                outNetworkDataBuffer.flip();
                int numBytesWritten = theSocketChannel.write(outNetworkDataBuffer);
                outNetworkDataBuffer.compact();

                if(finishHandshake(sslResult))
                {
                    DataToSend.rewind();
                    return SecureWrite(DataToSend);
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Write bytes
                outNetworkDataBuffer.rewind();
                Write(outNetworkDataBuffer);
            }

        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        writeSuccess = false;
    }

    return writeSuccess;

}

public ByteBuffer SecureRead() throws ReadTimedOutException
{
    int timeElapsed = 0;
    ByteBuffer ResponseBytes = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0);

    try 
    {
        //if we don't have a SSLEngine make one
        if(theSSLEngine==null)
        {
            setupSSL();
        }

        int consumedCount = 0;
        SSLEngineResult sslResult;
        do
        {
            //inNetworkDataBuffer.clear();
            inNetworkDataBuffer.put( Read() );
            inNetworkDataBuffer.flip();
            sslResult = theSSLEngine.unwrap( inNetworkDataBuffer, inAppDataBuffer );
            consumedCount += sslResult.bytesConsumed();     
            inNetworkDataBuffer.compact();

            if( sslResult.getStatus() == SSLEngineResult.Status.OK ) 
            {

                if(sslResult.getHandshakeStatus() != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NOT_HANDSHAKING)
                {

                    if(finishHandshake(sslResult))
                    {
                        return SecureRead();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    timeElapsed = 0;
                    inAppDataBuffer.flip();
                    ByteBuffer tempBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[ ResponseBytes.limit() + inAppDataBuffer.limit() ]);
                    ResponseBytes.position(0);
                    inAppDataBuffer.position(0);
                    tempBuffer.put(ResponseBytes);
                    tempBuffer.put(inAppDataBuffer);
                    inAppDataBuffer.flip();
                    ResponseBytes = tempBuffer;
                    ResponseBytes.flip();       
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //the status wasn't ok
                timeElapsed++;
            }
        }while(consumedCount < inNetworkDataBuffer.limit() && sslResult.getStatus() != SSLEngineResult.Status.OK);


    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    if(timeElapsed>=TimeOutThreshold)
    {
        throw new ReadTimedOutException();
    }


    return ResponseBytes;
}

public boolean Disconnect()
{
    try
    {
        theSocketChannel.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

public boolean isClosed()
{
    return !theSocketChannel.isOpen();
}

@Override
public String getHost() 
{
    return theRemoteAddress.getHostName();
}

@Override
public int getPort() 
{
    return theRemoteAddress.getPort();
}

public boolean isConnected() 
{
    return theSocketChannel.isConnected();
}


@Override
public boolean hasSecure() 
{
    return true;
}

public boolean finishConnect() throws Exception
{
    return theSocketChannel.finishConnect();
}

private void setupSSL() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException
{

    //create a new SSLEngine instance
    System.setProperty( "javax.net.debug", "ssl");
    TrustManager[] tm = new TrustManager[] { new NaiveTrustManager() };
    SSLContext theSSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance ("TLS");
    theSSLContext.init( new KeyManager[0], tm, new SecureRandom( ) );

    theSSLEngine = theSSLContext.createSSLEngine( theRemoteAddress.getHostName(), theRemoteAddress.getPort());
    theSSLEngine.setUseClientMode(true);

    inNetworkDataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[theSSLEngine.getSession().getPacketBufferSize()]);
    inAppDataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[theSSLEngine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize()]);
    outNetworkDataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[theSSLEngine.getSession().getPacketBufferSize()]);
    outAppDataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(new byte[theSSLEngine.getSession().getApplicationBufferSize()]);

}

private boolean finishHandshake(SSLEngineResult sslResult)
{   
    boolean bFinished = false;

    while(sslResult.getHandshakeStatus() != SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.FINISHED)
    {
        if( sslResult.getStatus() == SSLEngineResult.Status.CLOSED ) 
        {   
            bFinished = false;
            //break;
        }


        if(sslResult.getHandshakeStatus() == SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NEED_TASK)
        {
            Runnable task;
            while ((task=theSSLEngine.getDelegatedTask()) != null)
            {
                task.run();
            }

            try 
            {
                //outNetworkDataBuffer.flip();
                sslResult = theSSLEngine.wrap(outAppDataBuffer, outNetworkDataBuffer);
                //outNetworkDataBuffer.compact();
            } 
            catch (SSLException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        else if(sslResult.getHandshakeStatus() == SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NEED_WRAP)
        {
            try 
            {
                outAppDataBuffer.flip();
                sslResult = theSSLEngine.wrap(outAppDataBuffer, outNetworkDataBuffer);
                outAppDataBuffer.compact();
            } catch (SSLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if((sslResult.getStatus() == SSLEngineResult.Status.BUFFER_OVERFLOW) || (outNetworkDataBuffer.position() > 0))
            {
                try 
                {
                    outNetworkDataBuffer.flip();
                    int numBytesWritten = theSocketChannel.write(outNetworkDataBuffer);
                    outNetworkDataBuffer.compact();
                } 
                catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        else if(sslResult.getHandshakeStatus() == SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus.NEED_UNWRAP)
        {
            try 
            {
                int numBytes;
                //read data from the socket into inNetworkBuffer                    
                inNetworkDataBuffer.flip();
                sslResult = theSSLEngine.unwrap( inNetworkDataBuffer, inAppDataBuffer );
                inNetworkDataBuffer.compact();
                if(theSSLEngine.isInboundDone())
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    numBytes = theSocketChannel.read(inNetworkDataBuffer);
                    numBytes = numBytes;
                }

            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

Anyone have any tips on how to best establish this handshake with the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [Internet draft](http://www.web-cache.com/Writings/Internet-Drafts/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01.txt)? The CONNECT is received in plaintext. You form the upstream connection and return the 'HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established' response. After that the proxy isn't processing requests and responses, it is just copying bytes in both directions, whatever they may happen to be. Specifically, the proxy isn't concerned with SSL in any way shape or form.

Comment: Yeah, I did read a bunch of different stuff it just seems like when i try to send the response back to the browser in the case of the CONNECT it just keeps sending that same request back. It is not liking something. However, all my other http requests i send back to browser it accepts with no problems. I must be overlooking something. Maybe because of the Connect its assuming a new handshake is needed a cert or something. Honestly that is what I need to get clarification on.

Comment: @steve this really doesn't sound right. If the client gets back something it doesn't understand it should close the connection. There's nothing in the HTTP protocol that lets it send a second CONNECT on the same connection. Are you sure all these CONNECTs are arriving *on the same connection?*

Comment: Are you sure all these CONNECTs are arriving on the same connection?

Comment: Sorry, hit wrong key. No these CONNECTS are coming from different connections. I just can't get the darn browser to accept my response. Any ideas? Do I need to prepare a cert that the browser holds and i somehow send that with the connect back to browser?

Comment: @steve so if they are coming from different connections what exactly is the problem? This is what you should expect. If you are getting any data at all you cannot possibly have an SSL certificate problem. I believe the CONNECT is sent in plain text in any case.

Comment: So, here is what i see I fire up my proxy on port 8083 and refresh my browser to send request to https://encrypted.google.com/.

Comment: So, here is what i see I fire up my proxy on port 8083 and refresh my browser to send request to  https://encrypted.google.com/.                                       This is sent to proxy:                                                                           CONNECT encrypted.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110614 Firefox/3.6.18
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Host: encrypted.google.com . We send the this
 HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established\r\nProxy-agent: Ops Assistant\r\n\r\n

Comment: @steve this isn't getting us anywhere. If you get one CONNECT request on the connection, all you have to do is execute it, i.e. connect to the target and then start copying bytes in both directions asynchronously. Nothing to it really. If you get CONNECT on > 1 connections all you have to do is nothing because your code should already scale automatically to any number of clients. I still don't understand what the actual problem is.

Comment: The problem is that when I get the CONNECT. I send the connection established response to the browser in hopes that at that polint its going to start sending me requests via SSL. There is no data for me to start sending at this point. All the browser has given me at this point is a CONNECT which is not sent to the server right?

Comment: 'The problem is that when I get the CONNECT. I send the connection established response'. Exactly. You shouldn't send it *until you have established the upstream connection.* Otherwise you are just lying to the client.